# reproducir audio con - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Buen dia, implemente este plugin "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-player" sencillo y practico, pero tengo un inconveniente, cuando abro mi pagina con google chrome suena sin problemas inclusive desde el celular pero cuando abro la pagina desde un navegador safari no suena, alguien sabe como solucionar este inconveniente .

```js
import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';
//...
<ReactAudioPlayer
  src="my_audio_file.ogg"
  autoPlay
  controls
/>
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado con un archivo que no sea `.ogg`?

Comment: si, MP3 pero nada , y en Google Chrome funciona sin problemas

Comment: Has intentado no usar `autoplay`?

Comment: pero necesito que el audio se reproduzca solo, como hago si quito el autoplay?

Comment: Lo más probable es que Safari tenga una restricción para autoplay y por lo tanto no esté permitido. Si entras a las preferencias por sitio web de Safari. ¿Tu sitio tiene habilitado AutoPlay?

Comment: si, pero necesito que también me funcione en safari

Answer (score -1):

Safari tiene restricciones para que los sitios web puedan usar `Auto Play`. Como bien lo sugerí en los comentarios, debes verificar que tu sitio web tenga permisos en la configuración de Safari para usar `Auto Play`. Dicha configuración se encuentra en `Safari > Preferencias > Sitios Web > AutoPlay`.

[image: Safari settings]

Como lo muestro en la imagen, mi `localhost`, tiene activada la opción de `Allow All Auto-Play`. De esta forma, el autoplay puede funcionar.

En Mobile Safari, existen aún más restricciones y por lo tanto, no se permite que exista AutoPlay a menos que sea desencadenado por una acción del usuario, como un click. Lo cual esta bien. Imagínate tener múltiples pestañas y que de repente una este haciendo ruido y no sepas cual es.

Una solución a esto es que uses un banner de bienvenida y el cual sea forzoso que tu usuario de click en un botón para 1. desactivarlo y 2. para comenzar el audio, como en el siguiente código.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';

const audioURL = "https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-memories.mp3"

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      "muted": true,
      "playing": false,
    }
    this.audio = React.createRef();
    this.start = this.start.bind(this);
  }

  start() {
    this.audio.current.audioEl.current.play();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.start}>Start</button>
        <ReactAudioPlayer
          src={audioURL}
          ref={this.audio}
          controls
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: pero como hago para activar esta opción también en mi iPhone con safari?

Comment: Cuando abras tu página en Safari habrá un botón que es un `Aa`. Si das click en el podrás encontrar la opción de `Configuración de sitios`.

Comment: cuando entro a configuración de sitios en safari en el iPhone "Aa", solo deja activar la camara, microfono y ubicación, tambien se puede activar el lector pero da la opción que mencionas no aparece no la encuentro .